# Shared variable between tests

Tags: automated-testing, test-design

I have framework that has been written in Groovy, Spock and JUnit. Are there any way for getting variable from `CreateResource` class (after its execution) in `GetResource` class?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  CreateResource.class,
  GetResource.class
})
public class SimpleTestSuit {}
```

For example, I would like to book hotel in `CreateResources` class and will get booking number in `GetResources` class? In the same time, I want to save order of execution.

Maybe, there is any an approach for that. Either using some context, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you just need to set a publicly accessible variable (or an object with a getter/setter) in the GetResource class, from your CreateResource class. This approach works in **non-parallel** runs.

In JUnit it looks something like this:

```
public static string hotelReservation; // in the Test class or some other class that you reference

@Test
public void MyTest001() {
    //... perform actions
    hotelReservation = someElement.text;
}

@Test
public void MyTest002() {
    // do something with hotelReservation variable
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I mean other. I have two test scenarios, due this I would like to run first scenario (book hotel) and after second in which are using resource (booking number) from first. It's separated tests.

Comment: In my example, the first test sets the hotelReservation (booking number) and the second uses it . If the tests are in different classes, put the booking number in a separate class and make sure its accessible by the test classes.